# Use of uppercase in Cemetery Crypt Scripture

Tags: capitalization

Is it uppercase letters for the following?

- Nei nostri cuori per sempre /
  Nei Nostri Cuori Per Sempre
- Riposa in pace /
  Riposa In Pace

Comment: Rules for using the upper case ("Maiuscola") are very rigid in Italian, and they do not allow the usage you cited.

Comment: In the case of a personal cemetery scripture you can do whatever you prefer, it is just a question of personal style.

Comment: Related question: https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/24/ (I think it's essentially the same).

Comment: @Charo so you think that a dedication or an epitaph is the same as a title of a book or a newspaper article? Poor beloved dead...

Comment: No, @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: I think the rule is essentially the same.

Comment: As Gio says, a family grave is a personal thing, so the script should be left to personal taste, but capitalising all or most words is extraneous to any Italian usage. I'd go for either all caps or a sentence capitalisation (first word of the sentence/phrase and proper nouns).

Comment: Can someone write a proper answer?

Comment: @gio it seems that the OP is interested in some italian rule about the topic, otherwise she was not asking here.

Answer (score 3):

As explained in answers to [this other question](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/24/rule-to-capitalize-a-title), title case is quite common in English, but it's extraneous to Italian. So, I would say the standard way to write the examples of scriptures you propose in your question is simply use sentence case, in the following way:

- Nei nostri cuori per sempre
- Riposa in pace

Comment: Also take a look to a new answer to the question cited by the answer above: https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/11660/6017